# What does "contention-tost" mean?

Tags: poetry, meaning, matthew-arnold

In Matthew Arnold's 'Thyrsis: A Monody, to Commemorate the Author's Friend, Arthur Hugh Clough' we read:

> What though the music of thy rustic flute
>       Kept not for long its happy, country tone;
>       Lost it too soon, and learnt a stormy note
>       Of men contention-tost, of men who groan,
>       Which task'd thy pipe too sore, and tired thy throat--
>       It fail'd, and thou wage mute!
>       Yet hadst thou always visions of our light,
>       And long with men of care thou couldst not stay,
>       And soon thy foot resumed its wandering way,
>       Left human haunt, and on alone till night.

"Tost" (line 4) seems to be the past participle form of "toss". So can I assume that the phrase "contention-tost" in the same line means "throwing away disagreements" and "reconciling with each other"?

The whole poem is here:
https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43608/thyrsis-a-monody-to-commemorate-the-authors-friend-arthur-hugh-clough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a good find that "tost" is the past participle of "toss", but I don't think "contention-tost" means that contentions are tossed *away*. More the opposite, in fact: the men are tossed *by* contention.

Firstly, consider the **context**. The flute learns "*a stormy note / Of men contention-tost, of men who groan*": in conjunction with storminess and groaning, it doesn't sound like "contention-tost" is something peaceful and conciliatory.

Think of it by **analogy** with the word "storm-tossed". A [storm-tossed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/storm-tossed) sea is one *tossed by the storm* - wild and dangerous. Similarly, a contention-tossed man would be one *tossed by contention* - argumentative or bellicose, perhaps.

Finally, this isn't the only appearance of the word "contention-tost" in English literature. Let's check a few more examples of the word being used in context:

- > Thus Corinth had its partisans of old,
  >   With zeal as flaming as their love was cold:
  >   Some cry'd up Paul, and some Apollos prais'd,
  >   And some for Cephas clam'rous voices rais'd;
  >   Till **on the waves of fierce contention tost**,
  >   Their ark was founder'd, Christ and Truth were lost!
  >
  > <sub>-- [Timothy Touch'em, "The Age of Frivolity"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=M7NYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=contention-tost&source=bl&ots=FTXSQe5zDO&sig=17QepfExKVGVp7kWjqO8DTUqinc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihrcLGtJvZAhUpD8AKHYrnDQwQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=contention-tost&f=false) (emphasis mine)</sub>
- > When waters cover'd all the Earth,
  >   When Ocean's deepest Bed was driven
  >   With all his tow'ring waves to Heaven,
  >   And **in the fierce Contention tost**,
  >   The bounds of Sea and Land were lost
  >
  > -- [William Morgan, "Long Ashton"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DsvtYPzxJU0C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=contention-tost&source=bl&ots=vUEzJJmzgL&sig=KPrcp5AqBCy2T4esOve6x0LHfU0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihrcLGtJvZAhUpD8AKHYrnDQwQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=contention-tost&f=false) (emphasis mine)

So there we are. After all this evidence, it seems quite clear now that **"men contention-tost" means men made unruly by contention.**

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply.